# multiple line clob

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a `CLOB` column and every value in clob value spans multiple lines
and some of the lines are blank.

Example of the data:

```
abcd
ihuj

lkijhhusd
jjjjj
```

Now I want to write a query which will
generate `abcd;ihuj;lkijhhusd;jjjjj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REGEXP_REPLACE(my_clob,'[\r\n]+',';',1,0,'m')`

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html